# Which messaging queue for user messages

Tags: python, redis, message-queue, tornado

I have application (tornado) where users can send/recieve private mesaages to/from each other and also can chat publicly. I am using redis (brukva) pub/sub mesaaging for realtime chat but I cant decide which mesaaging queue system should I use for private messaging part since its not realistic to send and process messages in a single post/get request. I think queue will resolve this problem by processing messages in the background. Is redis can be considered as option in here or should I go with other messaging queue structures ? Any queue suggestions for that particular use case and why ??

Answer (score 2):

The Redis List data structure makes a perfect queue, with atomic [push](http://redis.io/commands/lpush)/[pop](http://redis.io/commands/rpop) operations and everything else you would expect from a queue.

Comment: When you're already hammering nails, you might as well use a hammer to hammer a tack. :-)